# Template parameters: is it legal to have constraints depending on other parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

#### Question

In the following code snippet:

```cpp
template<typename T, int val>
concept hasValue = (T::value == val);

// constraint on `wrapper` parameter depends on `val`
template<int val, hasValue<val> auto wrapper>
struct X {};
```

The type of the `wrapper` template parameter of `struct X` must satisfy the concept `hasValue<val>`, which is dependent on the other template parameter `val`. Is this program valid according to the c++20 standard ? ill-formed ? unclear ?

***Note:*** This is strictly a **language lawyer** question. I'm not looking for workarounds (a trivial one is to use a `requires` section after the template parameters).

---

#### c++20 Standard

I don't have access to the official one. Looking at the latest public c++20 draft, I assume [(temp.constr.decl)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.decl) is the relevant section. So far from my extremely limited understanding of this document, I couldn't find the answer to my question.

#### Compiler comparison

Using the following code snippet:

```cpp
template<typename T, int val>
concept hasValue = (T::value == val);

template<int val>
struct ValueWrapper {
    static constexpr int value = val;
};

template<int val, hasValue<val> auto wrapper>
struct X {};

struct Y {
    static constexpr ValueWrapper<2> wrapper2{};
    static constexpr X<2,wrapper2> x{};
};
```

On [godbolt (live demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/Yzb3dob8c):

- gcc-12.2 & clang-15 accept the code without warning, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.
- MSVC v19.33 refuses to compile with the following error on the declaration of `Y::x`: `error C7601: the associated constraints are not satisfied`. The compiler seems fine with the declaration of `struct X` itself, but evaluates the concept as `false` when declaring `Y::x`. I didn't find any related ticket in their bugtracker. **Edit:** I opened a [new report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Template-parameters:-constraints-dependi/10312655).

I don't know if gcc & clang are just nicer than what the standard requires, or if this is a MSVC bug.

---

#### Edit

- 2023-03-20: The [MSVC bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Template-parameters:-constraints-dependi/10312655) opened for this issue has been marked as "Internally fixed - pending release".
- 2023-08-09: Bug report closed. Visual Studio 17.7.0 now accepts this code (= MSVC v19.37.32822).

Comment: A template parameter can in general depend on previous parameters. A slight tweak to the code (use a type template parameter instead of a non-type one, that is `template<int val, hasValue<val> wrapper_t`) makes MSVC accept. I would say this is an MSVC bug with 95% confidence.

Comment: @n.m. After a bit more thinking, I also think MSVC's behaviour is a bug. The idiom `template<std::input_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S>` seems standard, and appears on [cppreference (std::ranges::for_each)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each) and in [Microsoft's STL implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/8eb3a067912f1362417c725ff679dda463f44087/stl/inc/algorithm#L287). This being well-formed with type parameters, but not with NTTP would be extremely surprising. I'll open a bug report at MSVC.